# Using ... function argument as input to another function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use ... to pass arguments into ggplot in a different function. For example:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(1, 2, 3))

f <- function(dat) { 
  ylimits = c(min(dat$x, dat$y), max(dat$x, dat$y))

  g(dat, ylim = ylimits)
}

g <- function(dat, ...) {
 args <- eval(substitute(alist(...)))

 ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + coord_cartesian(ylim = args[['ylim']])
}

f(dat)
```

I tried using eval(args[['ylim']]), various combinations of quote/deparse/substitute but I haven't been able to get it to evaluate properly.

Comment: Why not just `args <- list(...)`?  That works for me.

Comment: google 'R ellipsis'

Answer (score 0):

The environment of the previous function isn't passed along with the object, so if you save the call and then try to evaluate it the expression in `g` it won't be able to find `ylimits`, which only exists in `f`'s environment.

One option is to use the `lazyeval` package, but it is currently being deprecated in favor of [`rlang`](https://github.com/hadley/rlang), whose `dots_list` will do the trick nicely for you:

```r
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(1, 2, 3))

f <- function(dat) { 
    ylimits = c(min(dat$x, dat$y), max(dat$x, dat$y))

    g(dat, ylim = ylimits)
}

g <- function(dat, ...) {
    args <- rlang::dots_list(...)

    ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + coord_cartesian(ylim = eval(args[['ylim']]))
}

f(dat)
```

[image]